# Problem with json REST API connectivity on Power bi

Tags: json, database, powerbi, connection, database-connection

I have received an REST API json that contains data for analysis, it should have authentication, but when pasing few days (using datami=2023-05-01&datamf=2023-05-02) i connect without authentication, then when i pass an wide range o date (datami=2021-05-01&datamf=2023-05-02) it asks for authentication and when i pass the right user and password it says that the user/password is wrong (when its not, i tested in postman, its all fine theorically) or it connects and gives timeout...

I really don't know where to start at this problem, nothing seems to make sense to me, any ideas?

the link looks like this:
http://(the ip)/api/system/moviment/listmoviment?datami=2021-06-01&datamf=2023-12-31&$format=json&$dateformat=ISO

thank you all in advance!